# Facing error in Flutter: Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build an Instagram Clone and want to print the username of the user who is currently logged in.

Its showing current id as uid as per firebase when I use `print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);`.

But it showing null value when I print snap.data(), instead of all the details in the console

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MobileScreenLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const MobileScreenLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MobileScreenLayout> createState() => _MobileScreenLayoutState();
}

class _MobileScreenLayoutState extends State<MobileScreenLayout> {
  String username="";
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getUsername();
  }
  void getUsername() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap= await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();
    setState(() {
      username=(snap.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)['username'];
    });
    print(snap.data());
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Text('$username')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so most likely there is no document with the UID of the current user or that document doesn't contain a `username` field.

Answer (score 0):

From `firestore` the data you are trying to fetch that is not exists to ensure the data is available or not you can try this code

```
void getUsername() async {
 DocumentSnapshot snap= await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();
  if(data.exists){
   if(data.data()!.containsKey("username")){
    setState(() {
    username=(snap.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)['username'];
  });
  }
 }
}
```